# Proper template initialization in Eigen

Tags: c++, templates, eigen

Concerning proper parameter type deduction in Eigen.

I want to create a class that can either be initialized with a Matrix(`MatrixXd`) or Vector(`VectorXd`). The issue is that `MatrixXd` and `VectorXd` are both `typedefs` in Eigen:

```
// roughly
typedef Matrix<double, Dynamic, 1> VectorXd;
typedef Matrix<double, Dynamic, Dynamic> MatrixXd;
```

If I try to have two constructors overloaded with `VectorXd` and `MatrixXd`, I get `Ambiguous Constructor call` error.

Consider the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

class Container {
public:
    VectorXd a;
    MatrixXd b;

    Container(VectorXd a): a(a), b(MatrixXd::Zero(3,3)) {
        cout << "Initializing with vector" << endl;
    }

    Container(MatrixXd b): a(VectorXd::Zero(3)), b(b) {
        cout << "Initializing with matrix" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Container x(VectorXd::Ones(4));
    cout << x.a << endl;
    cout << x.b << endl;

    Container y(MatrixXd::Ones(4, 4));
    cout << y.a << endl;
    cout << y.b << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The exact error I get:

```
main.cpp:23:15: error: call to constructor of 'Container' is ambiguous
Container x(Matrix<double, Dynamic, 1>::Ones(4));
          ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:13:5: note: candidate constructor
Container(Matrix<double, Dynamic, 1> a): a(a), b(MatrixXd::Zero(3,3)) {
^
main.cpp:17:5: note: candidate constructor
Container(Matrix<double, Dynamic, Dynamic> b): a(VectorXd::Zero(3)), b(b) {
```

So the question is: How could I resolve which constructor I want to call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perfect forwarding, sfinae constrained constructors do work for your specific use case:

```
template<class T>
Container(T&& a,decltype(VectorXd{std::forward<T>(a)})* = 0): a(std::forward<T>(a)), b(MatrixXd::Zero(3,3)) {}

template<class T>
Container(T&& b,decltype(MatrixXd{std::forward<T>(a)})* = 0): a(VectorXd::Zero(3)), b(std::forward<T>(b)){}
```

but I'd suggest against using it (or anything equivalent), because there's no guarantee this will work for any matrix expression or for these expressions in future Eigen versions, because these conversions are not guaranteed to be sfinae friendly as far as I know.

I think it's better to provide more sensible overloads (depending on your actual use case), maybe something like

```
class Container {
public:
    VectorXd a;
    MatrixXd b;

    struct DefaultedT{};
    static constexpr DefaultedT Defaulted{};

    Container(VectorXd a,MatrixXd b): a(std::move(a)), b(std::move(b)) {}
    Container(VectorXd a,DefaultedT): a(std::move(a)), b(MatrixXd::Zero(3,3)) {}
    Container(DefaultedT,MatrixXd b): a(VectorXd::Zero(3)), b(std::move(b)) {}
};

int main() {
    Container x(VectorXd::Ones(4),Container::Defaulted);
    Container y(Container::Defaulted,MatrixXd::Ones(4, 4));
    ...
```

or just write a single constructor taking a matrix expression and perform the initialization logic accordingly ...

Comment: I like the options, but I don't think they address the question. I think that the last option (single constructor) is the most reasonable solution to the problem at hand. I was hoping there is a way to provide the type to the constructor (something of the `Container<Matrix<double,Dynamic,1>(x)` flavour. But this is clearly not possible without templating the class, which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: So is there no language feature for overloaded function template type resolution? Or is it just that such a feature does not work with value (e.g. `Container<int>`) template variety?

Comment: @Manbrosky, the problem are Eigen matrix expressions, they're designed to support a wide variety of implicit conversions, this conflicts with usual overloading strategies (see [here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicFunctionTakingEigenTypes.html) for general infos). You cannot reliably and generally overload functions without some help from the argument types.

Comment: alternatively, you can always ask your class users to commit the matrix type explicitly, as in *Container x(VectorXd{VectorXd::Ones(4)});* or *Container x(VectorXd::Ones(4).eval());*

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a very poor design, and I would strongly recommend to revisit it, perhaps using setters with adequate names. For instance, what if you pass a MatrixXd(4,1) ??

Anyway, to answer the question, you can use sfinae to detect wether the input is a vector or a matrix at compile time:

```
template<typename Derived>
Container(const MatrixBase<Derived> &a, typename std::enable_if<Derived::IsVectorAtCompileTime,void*>::type* = 0): a(a), b(MatrixXd::Zero(3,3)) {
    cout << "Initializing with vector" << endl;
}

template<typename Derived>
Container(const MatrixBase<Derived> &b, typename std::enable_if<!Derived::IsVectorAtCompileTime,void*>::type* =0): a(VectorXd::Zero(3)), b(b) {
    cout << "Initializing with matrix" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think this is a very poor design?